# Issue with bean creation after extending abstract class in servie

Tags: java, oop, grails

I have an abstract class defined in src/java of a grails project. A grails service is extending this abstract class. But after extending abstract class, no bean is getting created for the service and it throws nullpointer exception on accessing the service object.

Abstract Class in src/java is below

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {

  public abstract Boolean[] abstractMethod(final A a);
}
```

Grails Service class is below.

```
class XYZService extends MyAbstractClass {

  def someService

  @Override
  public Boolean[] abstractMethod(final A a) {
    println “Did something”
    return null
  }
}
```

Bean of service XYZService is not getting created. adding "def xyzService" in controller does not inject XYSService object.

Please suggest what might be the issue with this setup? Any configuration missing?

Comment: Not enough input. Maybe your abstract class ... is simply containing a bug. We can't help fixing your source code if you dont post any of it. In contrast to popular believe, we are no wizards here. We **do not know** how your setup looks like.

Comment: Update my code now. Please see what might be the issue now.

Comment: The signature `public Boolean[] abstractMethod(final A a);` is distint to `public Boolean[] processClientData(final A a) {` because  the name `"abstractMethod"` is no equals to `"processClientData"`!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Added @Component annotation to create the bean on Grails Service and it worked. Not sure if thats the right way to go as grails services ideally should be managed by grails itself but this seems to be working.